# Background/foreground color contrast fails Lighthouse test when JS adds a class that changes the theme of an element

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility, lighthouse, contrast

Firstly, I need this website I'm developing to score 100/100 in all Lighthouse tests: SEO, performance, accessibility and best practices.

Until now, my fixed navigation bar at the top of my page has a white background (#FFF) with #24292E foreground text using a 15px sans-serif font (font-family: sans-serif);

As the user scrolls down the page, one of the effects I've included changes the navigation bar colors based on the section they have scrolled to i.e. the navigation bar changes to a dark theme (adds 'dark' class) when it reaches a dark section and returns to the default light theme (removes 'dark' class) when it reaches a light section.

Without the Javascript change of class, my accessibility score is 100/100, meaning the contrast ratio test passed as dark text on white. With the Javascript change of class, the test annoyingly fails with light text on dark and one website contrast ratio checker tool reported that some links in the navigation bar now have #FFF background and #FFF foreground with a 1:1 ratio, which is not the case when looking at my website and not the case when you look at the CSS that has changed.

It seems that Lighthouse and other testers are having trouble determining which colors are used after the Javascript change and this annoys me because I'm meant to be building a 100/100 website with that particular effect and not sure how to move on from here. I have check contrast ratio tools to make sure those color combinations pass and they do.

Can anybody share an insight into what is happening and how to rectify it?

It's pointless sharing my JS code because it simply adds a class/removes a class when the browser is scrolled to a set waypoint and works as expected. I will, however, share my CSS (SCSS) to prove that it's not the issue:

```
#main-navigation {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    
    #main-navigation-links {
        li {
            a {
                color: #24292E;
            }
        }
    }

    &.dark {
        background: #24292E;

        #main-navigation-links {
            li {
                a {
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: A web page with light text and a dark background is failing the Lighthouse color contrast test]

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe because I'm only adding a class `dark` and then removing it, maybe Lighthouse and other testers are getting confused and seeing both the original styles and the newly-added styles. Maybe if I add the class `light`, remove the default styles, and then toggle the two classes, it may fix it. I will play with this tomorrow as it's late now.

Comment: This is one of those occasions where sharing a link to your site will be useful. In principle you have no problem but a missing closing tag somewhere can be enough to throw this off (as my guess is that an element is overlapping another and execution order and timing means the page is failing this test)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - I appreciate that would help but I'm not able to do that due to company policy. I have just run my codebase through a 'check closing tags tool', though, and nothing was found. I've also tried adding both 'light' and 'dark' classes and removed the original styles, as I suggested before, but wasn't the issue either. I've also removed the CSS classes entirely and tried to switch the CSS using Javascript but it still fails. This issue is baffling me but will continue with it for a while longer.